# Как правильно реализовать авторизацию в Spring Rest для мобильных и веб приложений

Tags: java, spring, rest, oauth, авторизация

Ребята помогите пожалуйста

Пытаюсь построить **Rest api** на **Java**, где клиентами будут
Мобильные приложения (Android, IOS)
И веб приложение.

И так, надо сделать авторизацию :
нативную и с помощью соцсетей (Google,Facebook,Vk
и возможно Apple ID).

Проблема следующая, я не совсем знаю ,как правильно реализовать авторизацию на Rest с мобильными и веб приложениями.
Уже практически все перечитал ,но ничего не прояснилось
(А возможно ,только больше запутался.
Изначально думал просто jwt вместо сессий и всё.)

Что я узнал

1. Использовать технологию единого входа (SSO)
2. Чтобы реализовать авторизацию для мобильных и веб приложений, нужно использовать **Oauth2**. Следовательно , Сервер Авторизации , Сервер Ресурсов и Клиент.
3. Вместо сессий токены jwt

Инструменты выбрал следующие:
**Spring Security + Spring Authorization Server + hibernate + MySQL**

Но когда начал собирать столкнулся с проблемой ,так как мобильные приложения - это паблик клиент ,
т.е использовать **Authorization Code + PKCE** ,но примеров реализаций нет .

Прочитал ,что есть такой **Keycloak**.
Но я не уверен ,что он мне подходит.
Где-то в коментах прочитал ,что он не совсем подходит для того ,чтобы сохранять юзеров в свою бд.

Подскажите пожалуйста ,
как правильно реализовать авторизацию в рест для мобильных и веб приложений .
И вообще  , на верном ли я пути?

И ,что для моего проекта будет больше подходить : **Keycloak**? **Ory Hydra**?

Я новичок с рест до этого не работал , а про Oauth относительно недавно узнал .

Буду благодарен за любую помощь)